# Switch from my Xcode versioned file to its github/gitlab web version

Tags: xcode, github, hyperlink, gitlab

I'm often sharing link to my code with my colleague using *Github* and *Gitlab* cool line anchor feature (ie: https://github.com/Phonations/Joker/blob/master/.travis.yml#L12-L16).

I'm looking for a way to quickly jump from my file to it's web version. Does anyone know a trick or an extension to perform this?

If it is possible to do it from the terminal, it'll be already nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this not (yet) perfect script:

```
if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then
    echo "Illegal number of parameters, usage: script file lineStart lineEnd";
    echo "Example : test.sh .travis.yml 12 16";
    exit 255;
fi

branch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`;
repo=`git config --get remote.origin.url | sed 's/\.git//g'`;

echo $repo"/blob/"$branch"/"$1#L$2-L$3;
```

To do so. Usage:

```
path/to/script.sh file lineStart lineEnd
```

If you want to copy it to clipboard (since I see you're on mac) pipe it to pbcopy:

```
path/to/script.sh file lineStart lineEnd | pbcopy
```

Of course you can wrap it to a function.

*Side note:* To use it `pwd` must be the root of your git repo.

Comment: In the same idea but more powerfull: https://github.com/paulirish/git-open

Answer (score 0):

I forked and patch to this nice XCode extension for *Github* and *BitBucker* which now work with *Gitlab*: https://github.com/larsxschneider/ShowInGitHub